# Can all python code be compiled by cython as is?

Tags: python, cython

I went through a few cython tutorials and felt comfortable beginning to mess around with my own conversion. The first thing I did was copy paste my python code and compile it to make sure it was working. However, the cython compiled code gives a different (and wrong) output, even though I didn't change a thing.

My understanding was that cython can compile python? I would link the code but it's fairly large in comparison to most code pasted. My biggest question is what types of python code isn't compiled correctly by cython when directly copied?

Comment: I think there's a few small omissions, but generally if it doesn't work it should be considered a bug. You should try to get a minimal example to show the issue then submit it to the [Cython issue tracker](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues)

Comment: The one thing you might want to check: it defaults to Python 2 semantics in a lot of cases, which affects things like the results from division. You can change this though.

Comment: Turns out the whole thing came to a half due to this line:

TM[adjMut[f]][i] = 1 / len(fitter)

In python this works great. In Cython I have to do:

TM[adjMut[f]][i] = 1.0 / len(fitter)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. In python my line of code read:

```
TM[adjMut[f]][i] = 1 / len(fitter)
```

In cython i had to declare the 1 as 1.0:

```
TM[adjMut[f]][i] = 1.0 / len(fitter)
```

In many hundreds of lines of codes, that's the only difference. I'm not sure if it's a bug or intended, but there it is!

Comment: This is I think what I suggested on a comment above - it's compiling it as if it's Python 2, where division worked differently. You could also use the [language_level](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiler-directives) directive to set it to Python 3 mode. Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: Yeah it was a helpful, however I wasn't quite sure how to change how it defaults. But your comment helped me find what types of comments to look at!